# inserting data into the table fields

Tags: javascript, json

Why I'm not getting the data added into the table every time I submit the data when entering data into the input fields and click on submit? The data should be updated into the table. I have used Javascript and JSON. I don't know which area in the code I have gone wrong.

```
<body>
    <fieldset id="styfe">
        <legend>Insert Data</legend>
        <input type="text" id="inpbok"> <br><br>
        <input type="text" id="inpdur"><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="inpct"><br><br>
        <input type="button" id="btninsert" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
    <br><br>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Local Storage</legend>
        <table id="isOutput">
            <thead>
                <th>BOOK </th>
                <th>DUR</th>
                <th>CT</th>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td id="bok"></td>
                <td id="dur"></td>
                <td id="ct"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="isOutput"></div>
    </fieldset>
</body>
<script>
    let pro = [{
            bok: "bok",
            dur: "01",
            ct: "1.25"
        },

        {
            bok: "saleem",
            dur: "08",
            ct: "1.29"
        }

        ];

    btninsert.onclick = function (bok, dur, ct) {
        if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userinput')) != null) {
            localStorage.setItem('userinput', JSON.stringify(pro));
        }

        let obj = {
            bok: document.getElementById('inpbok').value,
            dur: document.getElementById('inpdur').value,
            ct: document.getElementById('inpct').value

        }
        pro.push(obj);
        //console.log(person);
        localStorage.setItem('userinput', JSON.stringify(pro));

        // now we are going to store it in the localstorage 
        if (bok && dur && ct) {
            localStorage.setItem(bok, dur, ct);
            location.reload();
        }
    };


    for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        $('#bok').append("<td>" + localStorage[i].bok + "</td>");
        $('#dur').append("<td>" + localStorage[i].dur + "</td>");
        $('#ct').append("<td>" + localStorage[i].ct + "</td>");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: there are a lot of issues in our code, did you share the entire code here? you are using variables which are not defined, and references of the defined variables are incorrect too

Comment: yes i shared the entire code here.

Comment: yes i removed the variables which  i am passing through the parametere